# Make an admin only part on a page in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, admin

I want to create a page where admins and users both can be but, on 1 side of the page only an admin can view it, and on the other side both users and admins can view it.

I tried it with this code

```
$this->Auth->user(['role']['admin']);
```

this is the code in my controller in a function

and this is my view code

```
if ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role.admin')){
```

what i am trying to achieve is that the auth component checks the role of a user, and if it is admin  it should show the part of the page which is hidden to a user.

this is the error i get

Notice (8): Undefined index: admin [APP/Controller\BestellenController.php, line 17]

Comment: Simply make a condition like if($this->Auth->user(['role'] == "admin")..I think you can better handle these things with appController..

Comment: if i do that i get the following error,
 AuthHelper could not be found.

Comment: And in the documentation i cannot find anything about the auth helper

Comment: have you loaded auth component in appController ?

Comment: yes i have loaded it

Answer (score 1):

> *You can better handle authorization of action from AppController.*

In your AppController do something like this:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    $action = $this->request->params['action']; // request action
    if($action == "test") {
        if($user['role'] == 'admin'){
           return true;
        } else {
            // this page is for admin only
            echo 'You are not authorized to access the page.';
            // redirect('Somewhere');
        }
    }
}
```

The above function simply make 'test' action accessible to admin only. If you would like to do same thing for any action of any controller just check controller there as well.

And If you wish to make certain portion of view accessible to certain role only then:

```
$role = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role');
if($role == "admin") {
  // this is for admin
} else { 
  // this is for other
}
```

And I hope you have role field in users table.

Comment: I do not want that, 

for example

some text blahblah blah <- this should only be shown to the admin

some other text blahblah <- this should be shown to both user and admin

Comment: do you mean you wish to do that in view file ?

Comment: Complementing to the last part `$this->request->session()->read(...)` can be used on Views, Layouts, Templates and Controllers without problem.